# HTML/CSS style for having on fixed navbar two fixed sidebars and scrollable content with scrollbar at right of screen

Tags: html, css, flexbox, scrollbar, sidebar

```css
.navbar {
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(51, 204, 51);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
}

.dashboard {
  display: flex;
  top: 10%;
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

.sidebar {
  border-right: 1px solid #ededed;
  background: #36c;
  flex: 1 0 10%;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 5;
}

.data {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar">navbar</div>
  <div class="dashboard">
    <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

### Result

[image: Result]

The scrollbar is present in the middle of the screen. But I want to scrollbar to the extreme right. I want to implement the same using flexbox. I tried multiple steps but couldn't get the desired result. Pls help me with the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think with what you are trying to accomplish that using `position: sticky;` is your best bet. It's would be a challenge to get the scrollbar on the body and still have the fixed positioning of your sidebars. What I would do is set `sticky` on `sidebars` then use `top: 0;` to get them in place.

The only downfall to this solution (which is standard behavior) is that as soon as you reach the bottom of the scrollable content in `content` the sidebar's scrolls slightly. I added more content so you can see what I am referring to. This could be solved by setting a fixed 100vh container that contains all of this code and cannot be scrollable, then creating a scroll within that. You can also use `js`.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(51, 204, 51);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
}

.dashboard {
  display: flex;
  top: 10%;
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.sidebar {
  border-right: 1px solid #ededed;
  background: #36c;
  flex: 1 0 10%;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10%;
}

.one { 
  position: sticky;
  width: 10%;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.two {
  position: sticky;
  width: 10%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  flex: 5;
  width: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.data {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar">navbar</div>
  <div class="dashboard">
    <div class="sidebar one">sticky sidebar one</div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
      <div class="data">a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar two">sticky sidebar two</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks sir..this seems to work for me..